# Will there be a difference in my results if I set my data as nominal rather ordinal (using likert scale variables)

Tags: ordinal-data, likert, categorical-data

I have just received the results from a quesionnaire I did where some of the questions were in likert scale,  1 (Strong agree) to  5 (Strongly disagree), with Neutral in the middle. I would like to know if it would make any difference to my results if I set the data as nominal rather than ordinal as I've seen most people do e.g From youtube tutorials of how to input questionnaire data into SPSS where most people tell the statistical software that the data is ordinal when it is a likert scale question/variable.

For background, in my research I would like to do relationship analysis between some of the variables/questions as my research involves me looking at how recycling attitudes might influence behavior. Examples of my questions:

To what extent do you agree with the following?
"The natural environment is important to me" - (1)Strongly agree to (5) Strongly disagree

Please circle one.
"How often do you recycle?" - A.Almost Daily, B.2-3 times a week, C.Once a week, D. Less than once a week, E. I don't recycle

Edit: I have an addition thing I want to ask after seeing my "I don't know" item above so please bear with me. This question is for those familiar with using statistical software (especially spss).

If I choose to set my likert scale data as ordinal, will it make a difference if I set the value label "I don't know" with the numeric value as "6" or "0" in the statisical software? Is either better for analysis when the data is ordinal?

Comment: You have more statistical possibilities with ordinal data, for instance, the popular ordinal regression.

Comment: But whether I choose ordinal or nominal won't affect the validity or accuracy of my results right?

Comment: No. It had significant influence on how you would build your model and how you would interpret your model.

Comment: Hmm, may you elaborate or refer me to somewhere I can learn and see how they would affect the way I do my analysis?