# How do I fix the problem of having "expected count less than 5" warning message? (chi-square)

Tags: chi-squared-test, expected-value

I know theres a similar answered [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/what-to-do-when-i-have-expected-count-5-warning-for-a-chi-squared-test) to mine on this forum but I would like to ask a new question for my specific case and would also like to ask further questions for some of the answers that were given there as well.

I have just received the results from a quesionnaire I did where some of the questions were in likert scale, 1 (Strongly agree) to 5 (Strongly disagree). When I tried doing a chi-square test for independence for two question responses, I got the below results and warning message about expected counts being less than 5 for some cells. I've asked in another place about this and one person said to combine columns or eliminate respondents but I really don't want to remove or alter my data. Is there a way of fixing this problem without changing data too much that it'll affect the results?

Also in the other [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/what-to-do-when-i-have-expected-count-5-warning-for-a-chi-squared-test) that I earlier mentioned, someone commented that the chi-square test is "poorly disposed to handling varying numbers of categories within a single test". Is that the case with me? If, so what test should I use?

Further background: For my research, one of the thing I want to do is to compare the relationship between different variables such as recycling attitude and recycling behavior.

[image]

Comment: Since attitudes to recycling is an ordered categorical variable why not use ordered logistic regression?

Comment: The chi square approximation does not work well when you have such sparse cells.  You can use a form of Fisher's exact test.

Comment: To mdewey: I'm not familiar with regression but I'll give it a shot. Also, I'm still not sure whether to set my data as nominal or ordinal in my statistical software which is why I posted a question about this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277931/will-there-be-a-difference-in-my-results-if-i-set-my-data-as-nominal-rather-ordi?noredirect=1#comment533147_277931

But I think the answer is that ordinal is better since I have more options. So logistic regression a better tool to use in your opinion?

Comment: To Michael: I'm not familiar with Fisher's tests. What specific form is this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test